# Multiple entity managers in single repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have one repository in which I need to use another entity manager which holds different connection. This example does not work, because `$this->getEntityManager('anotherConnection')` gets same manager which is used by current repository:

```
class BlahRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->select('a')
                ->where('a.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id);
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        $repositoryFromAnotherManager = $this->getEntityManager('anotherConnection')
                 ->getRepository('Bundle:Entity');

        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $something = $repositoryFromAnotherManager->getTranslatedSomething($value->getSomething());
            $value->setTranslatedSomething($something);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

My question is: does it is possible to get other entity manager which holds other connection in repository. Note: this repository is called not by injecting it, so changing `getRepository` factory in services.yml is not a solution.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to make a custom service and inject the two repositories into it.  The only other way I can think of would be to override the doctrine repository factory service.  You can search for how to do this.

Comment: I think I will use service, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have used is: created manager service and injected into it 2 repositories. Of course if someone is injecting repository as service then you can rewrite factory doctrine repository service also. Thanks to @Cerad